# Greek letters in acronym

Tags: acronyms

I want to use the [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package for a list of acronyms. When posting Greek letters like such:

```
\acro{$\nu$}{frequency}
```

I get errors

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted
```

What does that mean and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See section "2.3 Defining acronyms" of `acronym`s documentation:

```
\acro{nu}[$\nu$]{freqency}
```

The first argument is the name to address the acronym (`\ac{nu}`, ...), the printed short form is taken from the optional argument. The name of the acronym can only be stuff that survive `\csname...\endcsname` like the argument of `\label` or `\ref`.